# Constraint a UIBarButtonItem's size in the navigaiton bar with iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I try to set UIBarButtonItem with different size images in the navigation bar. So I create a UIBarButtonItem based custom view and set the custom view's frame to constraint the UIBarButtonItem's width. It had been working well before I updated the software to iOS 11. That set custom view's frame to constraint the UIBarButtonItem's width seems no longer useful on iOS 11.

I used the image `defaultImage` with 120*120:

```
UIButton *leftCustomButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];

[leftCustomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem * leftButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftCustomButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[self.headerIconItem];
```

On iOS10, iOS9 the leftBarButtonItem's image is not stretched. It show's like:

[image: show on iOS 10]

But the leftBarButtonItem's image is stretched on iOS11. It show's in the picture below.

[image: show on iOS 11]

Is there have some ways to constraint UIBarButtonItem's width in the navigation bar on iOS 11?

Answer (score 7):

Starting with iOS 11 `UIBarButtonItem`s are now laid out using the auto layout engine, in your case when targeting iOS 11 you should say something like:

```
UIButton *leftCustomButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];

[leftCustomButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES;
[leftCustomButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES; 

[leftCustomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem * leftButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftCustomButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[leftButtonItem];
```

For more information you should see the [*Updating Your App for iOS 11*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/) WWDC 2017 session.

Comment: where does `headerIconItem` come from? Thanks

Comment: @Evusas I think that's just an oversight from the original post. I edited the answer to make it clear that once you create the bar button item you should set that to your view controller's `navigationItem` as the desired left or right bar button item(s).

Answer (score 0):

Applicable for Swift 5

```
let titleView = createTitleLabel() // Create UILabel view with specific settings
titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 165).isActive = true
let title = UIBarButtonItem(customView: titleView)
```