# iOS11 Right UIBarButton background image stretch

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

We are facing issue of image stretching on right UIBarButton on iOS11. till iOS 10 it was working fine.
we use below code:

```
[rightItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_DISABLED]
                         forState:UIControlStateDisabled
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[rightItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_ENABLED]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This code is being used in entire app and we just need to make minimal changes in appearance or base view controller.

Please help.

Image used for background is below:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Change edge inset

Comment: changing edge inset not working

Comment: Seeing the same after an update to iOS11. A break in the code reveals the proper dimensions still so i suspect it is a new auto layout issue.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363375/constraint-a-uibarbuttonitems-size-in-the-navigaiton-bar-with-ios-11